# How to delete special characters (such as `‘ŒðŸ’`) from tweets

Tags: python, regex, twitter, data-cleaning

I have to clean special characters such as `ðŸ‘‰ðŸ‘ŒðŸ’¦âœ¨` from tweets. In order to do that, I followed this strategy (I use Python 3):

1. Convert tweets from bytes to strings to get the special characters as hex, so `Ã` becomes`\xc3\`;
2. Using regular expressions, delete the `b'` and `b"` (at the beginning of the string) and the `'` or `"` (at the end of the string) added by Python after the conversion process;
3. Finally delete the hex representations, also using regex.

Here is my code:

```
import re
tweet = 'b"[/Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] to question\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc2\xa6 "'

#encoding to 'utf8'
tweet_en = tweet.encode('utf8')
#converting to string
tweet_str = str(tweet_en)
#eliminating the b' and b" at the begining of the string:
tweet_nob = re.sub(r'^(b\'b\")', '', tweet_str)
#deleting the single or double quotation marks at the end of the string:
tweet_noendquot = re.sub(r'\'\"$', '', tweet_nob)
#deleting hex
tweet_regex = re.sub(r'\\x[a-f0-9]{2,}', '', tweet_noendquot)
print('this is tweet_regex: ', tweet_regex)
```

The final output is: `[/Very seldom~ will someone enter your life] to question "` (from which I still couldn't delete the final `"`). I was wondering if there is a better and more straightforward way to clean special characters in Twitter data. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work fine, if you are only looking for ASCII characters:

```
initial_str = 'Some text ðŸ‘‰ðŸ‘ŒðŸ’¦âœ¨ and some more text'
clean_str = ''.join([c for c in initial_str if ord(c) < 128])
print(clean_str)  # Some text  and some more text
```

You can do `ord(c) in range()`, and give it a range of text you want to keep (may be to include emojis).